# Show Column Position In Google Scripts UI

Tags: google-apps-script

I like to limit all of my lines of code at 80 characters.

When writing scripts via the Google Scripts UI, I have no way to tell the current vertical position of my code.

Is there a setting I can enable that will draw a vertical line at column 80, or will display the current vertical position of my cursor as a number?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a Chrome Extension, if you ask me.

You should be able to accomplish a display attached to cursor indicating line character count with a combination of javascript/jQ, css and perhaps a decently written regular expression.

Within the Google Script interface, however, I don't suspect you'll find a solution that fits your needs.

Happy coding,
-B